# When doing logo design, how to deal with the license of the font used?

Tags: fonts, licensing, font-licensing

I have bought a bundle of fonts which I want to use in a logo design for a client. The terms and conditions state the following:

> with this you can:
>   Use these resources within personal and commercial projects, as well as items for sale. The resources must be used with in a wider design though, and not comprise the entire design. This can include, but is not limited to posters, t-shirt designs, digital goods, merchandise etc…
>   You cant:
>   Resell this files directly, or within items/goods where they can be extracted in their original form. Share this resources with others. This is a single user license."

So, can I use the fonts for logo design? if so, what happens to the license of the font? Do I have to buy another license to be transferred to my client? Or is it ok to use without getting another license because I am basically using the font for one or two words and not actual paragraphs of text.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

As it says right there in the conditions, **you can use it in the logo as long as the text using the font is not the only part of the logo**. Something must be added or removed.

> The resources must be used with in a wider design though, and not comprise the entire design

And, of course, you can only provide images using it, not the font file itself.

Answer (score 3):

Logo aren't typically delivered to clients as fonts. It's not live, editable text but rather the outline of the particular text. So there's no need to transfer the font files along with the logo itself. If, for whatever reason, the client wants or needs a copy of the font, yes, they'd need to purchase a license for it.

On first read, I also share Zach's opinion...it sounds like you can use the fonts as *part* of a logo but not *as* the logo. Which is admittedly rather odd. It's also open to interpretation as while the logo may be pure text, the logo itself is usually part of a larger design. I'd email the type foundry for clarification on that.

Comment: Even if the logo does not have any elements apart from text rendered in this font, most logos would arguably constitute a ‘wider design’ in themselves, since they're rarely just a word written in a given font. There's usually a good deal of colour and placing going on that would make it a design (whether a wide or a narrow one).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yea, I agree. There seems to be enough loopholes in the definition of 'wider design' to make it applicable to nearly any situation.